# Editor script has broken sliders after passing in the min/max values for the sliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, i spawn random objects at random time from a given range. I wanted the developer to have sliders that use ranges to prevent him from making any logical errors (the minumum value for the float `maxValue` is the float `minValue` and the maximum value for the float `minValue` is the float `maxValue`, both of which are public floats in the original GameManager scripts). The catch is that both values depend on each other (But they are still initialized: `minValue = 0f; maxValue = 1f`. But this just breaks the sliders (they get stuck at their positions).

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
[CustomEditor(typeof(GameManager))]
public class GameManagerEditor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty minSpawnRate;
    SerializedProperty maxSpawnRate;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        minSpawnRate = serializedObject.FindProperty("minSpawnRate");
        maxSpawnRate = serializedObject.FindProperty("maxSpawnRate");
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.UpdateIfRequiredOrScript();

        EditorGUILayout.Slider("Min Spawn Rate", minSpawnRate.floatValue, 0f, maxSpawnRate.floatValue);
        EditorGUILayout.Slider("Max Spawn Rate", maxSpawnRate.floatValue, minSpawnRate.floatValue, float.MaxValue);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

But i ended up with sliders that stay stuck which won't move. If i try to change the value by entering one, it just reverts to the old value immediately (As shown in the image below):
[image: Sliders]

Could someone explain the cause of this error and how i can fix it?

Edit: (**IMPORTANT**) I inserted dummy values for the sliders, tried out the int slider and everything but it seems the sliders stay broken. I followed the steps from [here](https://blog.theknightsofunity.com/use-customeditor-customize-script-inspector/) and i feel that something might be outdated.

Comment: 1. Have you thought about using a [MinMaxSlider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.MinMaxSlider.html) instead? 2. float.MaxValue is quite large. You should give your designer a reasonable max value (e.g. 100), because the slider can't display that many steps properly and you probably do not want a spawn rate that high.

Comment: @MaxPlay 1. Just tried that, the slider is still stuck. 2. I attempted that before (that too, coincidentally, with the same value) but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
minSpawnRate.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider(minSpawnRate.floatValue, 0, maxSpawnRate.floatValue);
maxSpawnRate.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider(maxSpawnRate.floatValue, minSpawnRate.floatValue, float.MaxValue);
```

The tutorial was right, just needed to have the values set. Edit: I forgot the labels, but you can add them